# Manipulating a CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

At the moment I am working on a script to automate a process in IE to add Computer Names and their MACs so we can image them. The page has two fields one for MAC and one for a computer name then a add new button. I had to come to a pretty sloppy solution for avoiding a popup from the page by just quitting out of the com object after submitting.

I don't have much experience with Powershell yet and none with working with CSVs so I'm having a bit of trouble making this work. My goal is to have the script read two entries from a row fill out the correct field then submit it then move to the next row and repeat.

Right now what it does is fills out the fields with undefined in both fields, then submits and repeats.

EDIT: I have edited my code slightly just so it confirms what is trying to read.[This is what the results look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ktSs.png) I believe @WalterMitty is on to something that something is wrong with $ie.document.getElementsByName lines, I just tried $ie.document.getElementById but that didn't fill out any fields. It seems it has no problem reading the CSV, but it does have a problem entering the information it reads into the fields properly.

This is an example of what the CSV would look like.

```
 NewComputerName,NewMACAddress
 ComputerName1,111122223333
 ComputerName2,112233446677
 ComputerName3,AAAABBBBCCCC
 ComputerName4,AABBCCDDEEFF
```

This is what my code currently looks like.

```
cls

$URL = ""
$iterator = 1;
$csv = Get-Content C:\example1.csv

foreach($row in $csv)
{


#starts IE
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($URL)

while($ie.Busy -eq $true) { start-sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

($ie.document.getElementsByName("mc_id") |select -first 1).value = $_.NewComputerName;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("mac_id") |select -first 1).value = $_.NewMACAddress;
$ie.document.forms | Select -First 1| % { $_.submit() };

$ie.quit()
$iterator++

write-host "$iterator new ID(s) added"
write-host $row.NewComputerName - $row.NewMACAddress
}
```

Comment: Use `Import-CSV` instead of `Get-Content` and when you're looping over `$row in $csv` then use `$row` instead of `$_` to access things.

Comment: Still seems to spit out undefined.

Comment: [... no it doesn't?](http://i.imgur.com/Owaeudn.png).

Comment: I agree this works for write-host, but for some reason when it is entering into the fields it puts undefined.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't bugs in the rest of your code?  How does your code navigate to the correct page, when all you've given it is $URL pointing at nothing?  Are you sure that the two steps that use "getElementsByName" work when you test them interactively?

Comment: @WalterMitty I left the url blank on purpose for posting here. How should I go about testing them interactively?

Comment: *for some reason when it is entering into the fields it puts undefined* - Is the reason that you're still using `$_`, which is undefined? `($ie.document.getElementsByName("mc_id") |select -first 1).value = $_.NewComputerName;` should be `$row.NewComputerName` and similar.

Comment: So, does $URL get a different value for each iteration through the loop?  Or does it always reference the same page?

Comment: Do something like $ie.document.getElementsByName("mc_id") | select -first 1  interactively, and see what it gives you.  Then see if you can set .value to the computer name from the first row of the csv file, and see if that works?

Comment: Have you done scripting before in some other scripting language?  Which one?  Have you written computer programs in some programming language?  Which one?

Comment: It seems you had two problems.  One was to get the data out of a CSV file.  The other one was to put thar data into a web page.  If one of the answers has solved the first problem for you,  suggest you accept it.

Comment: If you are still having trouble wth the second problem, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$URL = ""
$iterator = 1

# use Import-Csv for CSV files
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\example1.csv" -Delimiter ","

foreach($row in $csv) {
    Write-Host "$iterator new ID(s) added"

    #starts IE
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.Visible = $true
    $ie.Navigate($URL)

    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

    # $_ is not defined in foreach blocks, you have to use $row here
    ($ie.Document.getElementsByName("mc_id") | Select-Object -First 1).Value = $row.NewComputerName
    ($ie.Document.getElementsByName("mac_id") | Select-Object -First 1).Value = $row.NewMACAddress

    $ie.Document.Forms | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object { $_.submit() }

    $ie.Quit()
    $iterator++
}
```

Comment: Still seems to spit "Undefined" in both fields

Comment: Added the CSV delimiter, I cannot think of anything else causing this. Please inspect the contents of `$csv`.

Comment: Still doesn't change it.

Comment: @sodawillow maybe provide just a little more context/explanation (even inline comments) than just code

Comment: You're right, I have added comments where I made changes. Still, I am puzzled by the OP's results.

Comment: I think your braces need to be balanced.

Comment: @WalterMitty Yes? Where? Read the whole thing multiple times + ISE is not complaining.

Comment: Sorry.  I wasn't seeing the close brace at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar issues but I just found this may help you guys - I don't have 50 reputation to comment sorry :/....

I messed around with the `-Path` of the `Import-CSV` command but I just couldn’t make it work. Apparently this has nothing to do with the path of the CSV file.  The Warlock posted this on his blog:

> Long story short, the error came from having trailing blank columns in
>   my CSV. `Import-Csv` uses the first row in the CSV as names for the
>   columns (unless you specify otherwise) and when you have blank columns
>   (or at least multiple blank columns) it causes this error as it
>   doesn’t have a valid name for them.

Instead of changing the file, I changed my import command to include the headers as per Dale's comment and it worked perfectly:

```
$data = import-csv "C:\Sharepoint.csv" -header("Department","AD Group","Members","Notes")
```

The Warlock and Dale saved me lots of time, please stop by [the Warlock’s blog](http://pinchii.com/2011/09/cannot-process-argument-because-the-value-of-argument-name-is-invalid/) and give them a big Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Import-Csv and Invoke-WebRequest in combination, e.g. like this:

```
import-csv .\example.csv | %{ iwr http://someurl.local -body @{mc_id=$_.NewComputerName; mac_id=$_.NewMACAddress} -Method POST }
```

It will read the csv file, iterate over the records and create a application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request with the values from each record.

When you use iwr (Invoke-WebRequest) and pass a hash table as the "body" it will act as if it is a form being submitted. The POST method will submit the form values as application/x-www-form-urlencode. Without the POST method it would submit the form as if it was a GET, i.e. pass the values in the url.

If you need authentication, session support etc. then read the documentation for Invoke-WebRequest.

Using IE to automate web requests is brittle and error prone.